# How do I loop and iterate a row in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning programming and have an issue. I would like to iterate and loop (i think are the terms) a row. The row will contain 3 columns who's data comes from a REST api. Once the row has 3 columns fulled, I would like a new row to be created with 3 more columns.

What is the easiest way to achieve this thanks.

My code is here https://jsfiddle.net/Ory4n/8k7dabyr/1/ and I found a possible solution code here https://jsfiddle.net/dya52m8y/2/ however I do not know how to implement that code into my own project as of yet.

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      pages: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let pagesURL = "http://creartem.nz/wp-json/wp/v2/projects";
    fetch(pagesURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        pages: response
      })
    })
  }
  render() {
    let pages = this.state.pages.map((page, index) => {
          return (
              {/* Start Loop */}
            <div key={index}>
        <h2>{page.title.rendered}</h2>
      <p>{page.acf.technologies}</p>
      <p>{page.acf.team}</p>
      </div>
       {/* end Loop */}
          )
        })
        return (
          <section>
              {pages}
          </section>
        );
  }
}


export default Test;
```

Comment: What is your final aim to have those rows and cols, a table? Will you have more objects like in your API response in the future then you want to create a table using those objects?

Comment: Hi, my aim is to setup a portfolio page. Each portfolio item will be in a row. Each row will contain 3 portfolio items pulled from the API. I do not want to create tables. More items in future will be added. So the app needs to be able to create a new row and new columns when first row is full. Hope that makes sense, and thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render an array of components, you must call a function that in turn returns a call to the `.map()` method you had specified. See below:

```
render() {

    const renderPages = () => {
        return this.state.pages.map((page, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <h2>{page.title.rendered}</h2>
                <p>{page.acf.technologies}</p>
                <p>{page.acf.team}</p>
              </div>
            );
        })
    }

    return (
      <section>
        {renderPages()}
      </section>
    );
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, getting one step closer. That duplicates the row, but doesn't put the items in the columns, it just creates a new row with 1 column in each row. I will try resolve this, should be an easy fix. Just a matter of moving the index key to a new div. Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Hi its me again, thanks very much for your assistance. All I needed to do was add the index key to the column. Everything is working now, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but if I understand correctly, you would like to create a new row containing a h2 and two p tags. You could try using a table to achieve this output. Something like:

```
const renderPages = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                 <th></th>
                </tr>
                {this.state.pages.map(page => {
                    return (
                        <tr key={page.id}>
                         <td><h2>{page.title.rendered}</h2></td>
                         <td><p>{page.acf.technologies}</p></td>
                         <td><p>{page.acf.team}</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also, avoid using index as your key. It causes weird issues. Use something like an id.

Here is a similar example on codepen: https://codepen.io/mkempinsky/pen/gBapqg?editors=1111